# choose list to append based on result python

Tags: python, list

I have three lists: list1, list2, list3. I have a random number generator based on the number generated i want to select the list to append the value
Example code:

```
import random
list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
for i in range(0,100):
    x= random.randint(0,2)
    list+"x?".append(i)
```

how to select the list based on value of x. How can I do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to create a temporary variable, that contains the lists that you want to append stuff to. Here is a simple example:

```
>>> list1=[]
>>> list2=[]
>>> list3=[]
>>> x = [list1, list2, list3]
>>> random.choice(x).append("This is the input")
>>> x
[[], ['This is the input'], []]
>>> list1
[]
>>> list2
['This is the input']
>>> list3
[]
>>>
```

See that input is appended to `list2` even though it's inside of `x`? This is because, when you created `X` we gave it a reference to the variable `list2` not the values themselves.